# How can i create new react native App using npx?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, react-native, mobile

I didn't use react-native for a few months. It looks like some things have changed meanwhile. In the official documentation they recommend to uninstall `react-native-cli` and to use`npx react-native init` instead. I did this but ended up with an error because I didn't install that package globally. However, if I install `react-native` globally, it results in an error when I run the project, saying that I should remove the global package.

What is the proper way to create a react app nowadays?

Answer (score 15):

1. npm uninstall --global react-native-cli
2. Install node js (**i use node js version 12.10.0 [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.10.0/)**), i dont use the latest one because there is a bug i cant run my react native app
3. install **python2** **jdk8** and **yarn**
4. install android studio and sdk and add ANDROID_HOME to environment variable
5. use `npx react-native init ProjectName` to create new project
6. use `yarn react-native run-android` or `yarn react-native run-ios` to run the project

@Raeygzz
if you want to use react-native related command add yarn/npx in the beginning of the command

```
yarn react-native run-android
yarn react-native run-ios
```

or

```
npx react-native run-android
npx react-native run-ios
```

1. if you want to create apk debug use
   in your root project

   cd android && gradlew assembleDebug
2. apk release
   in your root project

   cd android && gradlew assembleRelease
3. Debug with bundle
   in your root project

   yarn react native run-android

and get the apk file in

```
android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug
```

i usually do this if the device i working on doesn't have an usb cable, so i copy the file there, and sent it to the cloud, download it to device and install it, after that i just shake the phone and go to settings and setup debug server
ex: 10.xxx.xxx:8081
then run yarn start in cmd
shake the device and choose refresh

the difference is here between react-native run-android and gradlew assembleDebug
[react-native run-android Vs ./gradlew assembleDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901338/react-native-run-android-vs-gradlew-assembledebug)

Answer (score 2):

Check their official document [npx](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is **delete** react-native-cli:

`npm uninstall react-native-cli` or `npm uninstall --global react-native-cli`

Then, install Expo CLI if you have NodeJS 10 LTS or greater installed:
`npm install -g expo-cli`

You should be able to make new react native app now with expo-cli like that : 
`expo init ProjectName`

Expo is a tool that allows you to set up a development environment on your phone. For more information, see the documentation here: https://expo.io/

It is the most efficient and fastest way to develop, test and deploy an application

Comment: Thank you, and if I want to create it without expo-cli? 
I used to create my apps using react-native-cli.

Comment: Why you want to do this ? This still the best way to set up a develoment environement on your phone. You can still use the react-native-cli, unistall it before and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gus Nando for the detail... and if i want to make a debug build for android using npx then what should i follow.  And also if there is any changes or change in set of way to create debug as well as production build for both android and ios platform.

Any kind of info related to npx will be of much help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `npx react-native init projectName`
then change directory to project with `cd projectName`
and run the project with `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

it's easy! in case of developing in windows just do the following command in your prefered terminal with administrative access:
npx react-native init YourPrjName

for details take a look at this brief video https://youtu.be/A5pXsiBVKTY

and don't forget to use lower case except for project name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).