# react-native installation error with npx react-native

Tags: windows, react-native

I'm trying to install react-native on Windows by entering command

```
$ npx react-native
```

and it shows error

```
You did not pass any commands, run `react-native --help` to see a list of all available commands.
```

is their something need to pass at the place of `<command>` in `npx react-native <command>`

Comment: This seems to solve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59325390/12637199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allready installed node js, then run the commons

`npx react-native init YourProject`.

It will download all the resources required for your project.
And when resources are downloaded, move to project folder
`cd YourProject`
And then type command

```
npx react-native run-nadroid
```

Make sure either emulator is running or your device is connected with your pc.